# SocketTimeOutException for Docs Api

Tags: google-drive-api, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-data-api

I am using Google Document AclFeed APi to get the list of users to whom the document is shared. This is the code I am using

```
AclFeed aclFeed = docsService.getFeed(new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/file%3A"+fileId+"/acl"), AclFeed.class);//No I18N
```

Until last week everything was working fine , but from past two days I am getting the SocketTimeOutException for many requests...Is anyone else facing this issue? Any help will be grateful..

TIA,
VijayRaj

Answer (score 0):

It happens a lot. What is your timeout set to? As an example the default on AppEngine is 5s which is way to low.